# How can I retrieve data from column between two dates in JSP

Tags: sql, jsp

I have inserted data with date stamp using DATE() and I have date in mm/dd/yyyy format in database. Now I want to retrieve some data from the database between two dates on a JSP page. Could anyone help me with my query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably too broad to be answered here. Please try to specify for example what technology are you using for data access (some ORM like Hibernate, plain JDBC, ...). Ideally also share some of your code or some solution you have already tried without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a column of type DATE, queries with < and > will work.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE DATE_FIELD > '2014-01-01' AND  DATE_FIELD < '2014-06-01'
```